# Bootstrap datepicker for Ruby, disable dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-datepicker

I need to create 2 date inputs(start and end date) using Bootstrap datepicker for Ruby and it looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= label_tag :import_start_date, I18n.t('modal.form.start_date'), class: 'col-lg-3 control-label required' %>
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <div class="bs-component">

      <%= text_field_tag 'start_date',
        Date.current.to_s,
        class: 'form-control',
        'data-provide' => 'datepicker',
        'data-date-format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        placeholder: I18n.t('modal.form.start_date'),
        autocomplete: 'off' %>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="border: 0">
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag :import_end_date, I18n.t('modal.form.end_date'), class: 'col-lg-3 control-label required' %>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <div class="bs-component">

        <%= text_field_tag 'end_date',
          Date.current.to_s,
          class: 'form-control',
          'data-provide' => 'datepicker',
          'data-date-format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
          placeholder: I18n.t('modal.form.end_date'),
          autocomplete: 'off'%>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Everything works, but I need to add some sort of validation so that the user can't select an "end_date" smaller than the "start_date" and vice versa. 
I searched the Internet and I found how to do it using Jquery. But I was wandering if there are some properties that I can use to avoid writing JavaScript code.

Any ideas?

The datepicker that I use:
https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails

Comment: could you post a link to the datepicker you use?

Comment: @mrzasa, I adapted the question

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`date-range` option](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/markup.html#daterange), prob. like this:

```
<div class="input-group input-daterange">
   <!-- your start_date and end_date inputs go here -->
</div>
```

Comment: I managed to create the range but it still allows me to select an end date smaller than the start date

Comment: I can't see any option for this, you probably have to write some simple JS.

Comment: Yes, I will do that.